# Hibernate mssql-jdbc driver generated query (multi column where clause) not supported by MS SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

When I try to get all the rows from a table using my JPA repository the query Hibernate is generating is like this:

```
Select field1, field2, ... from ... where (field1, field2) IN (select f1, f2 from ....)
```

It is working properly when my db is MySQL. Now I am trying to migrate to Ms SQL Server.

My repository looks like this:

```
@Override
public List<Books> getAllBooks() {
    return this.booksRepository.findAll();
}
```

The data model has a parent entity that and has a relationship OneToMany to the children using a composite key.

The error that I am getting is: 
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

This is due to **"where (field1, field2)"**. The query is generated by the driver itself so I am not able to do anything about it.

Any leads are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you remember to change the Hibernate dialect from MySQL to SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I did. There are some other queries that just run fine. Few of them don't and give error mentioned above.